# Delete ACL entry from the manage ACL list of the storage account in Azure using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-storage

For a specific directory/folder there are list of ACLs for which the permissions are provided. The requirement is to delete specific ACL entry from the manage access control list.

Below command only helps to remove the permission of the ACL. But the entry will be still present in the manage access control list

```
$filesystemName = "my-container"
$userID = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$acl = Set-AzDataLakeGen2ItemAclObject -AccessControlType user -EntityId $userID -Permission "---"
Remove-AzDataLakeGen2AclRecursive -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName  -Acl $acl
```

Can you please help us with the PowerShell command to delete the entry ..?

Comment: Where do you that it is not removed?

Comment: Ideally the entry should be deleted from the manage access control list of the storage account.
Remove commands just makes the permission empty. The entity/ACL will be still present in the list

Answer (score 0):

Try with this example which clears the entry from ACL List

```
$id = "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"

# Create the new ACL object.
[Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]]$aclnew =$acl

foreach ($a in $aclnew)
{
    if ($a.AccessControlType -eq "User"-and $a.DefaultScope -eq $false -and $a.EntityId -eq $id)
    {
        $aclnew.Remove($a);
        break;
    }
}
Update-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $dirname -Acl $aclnew
```

For more details refer this document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-acl-powershell

Comment: Same output from this approach as well. Basically the permissions are getting removed or can be told it gets changes to (---) but the AD group entry will be still present the manage access control list.

Comment: Can you please show the how the output looks?